# Checking if a method is an overridden method of Interface using reflection

Tags: java

I am trying to auto generate some EJB service code, which are wrappers around Java DAO classes. DAO classes implement DAO interfaces, but also have their own public methods. This DAO layer is implemented by another team, so I cannot play around with it.

I am using CodeModel API to generate the code. I get each DAO class and want now to create the EJB Service code. Using java reflection I am trying to check if the method declared in the DAO class is an overridden implementing method of the interface or not. Is there anyway in which I can check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If overridden methods are with @Overridden annotation, than you could iterate through these methods, and check their annotation using this API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getDeclaredAnnotations%28%29

2) If there are no annotations, I think, the only way is to iterate through parent classes and interfaces and compare method signatures, declared there with signatures in your class.

Comment: The problem is there may or may not be annotations

Comment: Than you can't check for annotation and need to compare signatures, as I menthioned in 2). One of the examples: http://robsanheim.com/2005/12/08/using-reflection-to-determine-if-a-method-is-overloaded/

Comment: yea I have seen that. and implemented the 2nd route.

Comment: That won't work, because the retention of @Override is SOURCE, so it will not be added to the bytecode and it is therefor not available at runtime.